# Bulk Insert Resulting in 0 Rows Affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

so I'm having some issues with the bulk insert query and I was hoping someone on here could help me figure out the issue. Below is my Bulk insert:

```
BULK INSERT [DB_Test].[dbo].[1_Import_ATT_tbl_GPSD]
FROM '\\IP Address\Folder\CSV_FIle.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '/n',  
TABLOCK
)
```

I've checked the row terminators in the source file and they end with LF, but I've tried every row terminator I can think of, and they all result in 0 rows affected. The source file is a simple 13 column CSV, and I can't seem to get anything imported. Is there something I'm missing? I know it has nothing to do with permissions, as I've already checked. Any ideas?

Comment: \n is newline row termination

Comment: @zedfoxus Stupid mistake on my part, but still resulting in 0 rows affected!

Comment: Bring that file locally on the system where you are running bulk insert. Create a folder and give Everyone read rights to it. Try bulk insert again.

Answer (score 2):

The rowterminator is wrong.

Should be:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
```

Comment: What if you change to FIRSTROW = 1 ?  Does that successfully import 1 row ?